# Using Postresql, identify IDs if they have three or more boolean columns matching the premises

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to identify customers by their recurring purchases. For that I have a table with the distinct customer IDs and several columns with the year and month (`YYYY-MM`) filled in by a boolean that identifies whether the customer made any purchases in the month (`0` does not have a purchase and `1` does), as shown below:

| customer_id | 2020_03 | 2020_04 | 2020_05 | 2020_06 | 2020_07 | 2020_08 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12346 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 12347 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 12348 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12349 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

In the case above, if we define that a recurring customer has purchases in **three consecutive months**, then only customers `12345` and `12346` fit this premise.

The question I'm stuck with is: **is there any way to be able to identify these customers if they have three booleans in a row marked with 1, or if I need to process my data in some other way to achieve the goal?**

Comment: You say that the column is a boolean (true/false), but your sample data shows numbers (0/1) - which is it?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if the model was properly normalized

Comment: In PostgreSQL boolean values are "true" or "false". Are you using real booleans, or are you using numbers to represent booleans?

Comment: TheImpaler and a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the comment. In this case I'm using numbers to represent booleans.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what you mean about being normalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all columns into a single string and then look for the sequence `'111'` in it. For example:

```
select *
from t
where '' || "2020_03" || "2020_04" || "2020_05"
         || "2020_06" || "2020_07" || "2020_08" like '%111%'
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Very efficient answer!